# How can I prevent Linux from slowing down under load?

Tags: linux

When I have processes consuming large amounts of memory or I have many CPU bound processes running it often becomes difficult to even log in to the system.
I would like to prevent that and always keep the system responsive. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Clarifying edit:

I am talking about two different situations in which I experience the same symptoms:

1. Very high memory load. A single process consuming close to or more than the available 64GB of RAM. When the system gets close to 100% usage programs become unresponsive.
2. Very high CPU load, scheduling issues. Having 10k runnable processes causes the same issue. Note that this is not a problem of 100% CPU load. When I kill -STOP all but 200 of those processes all 32 CPUs stay at 100% load but the system is much more useable.

And on the issue of what I consider "the system". I understand that there is no conceptual difference between a shell process and one of my other user processes but that's just a matter of making them different. There are options like niceness that do just that. But as mentioned above, niceness did not solve the problem at least not in case (2.).

I have complete control of these systems and have in all cases been able to stop jobs using kill -STOP or just C-c. **What I would like to fix is that this becomes incredibly difficult and when using a GUI sometimes impossible because input is processed incredibly slow if at all.**
I would like to fix this in general not make changes to some specific jobs.

Things I have tried:

1. For many running processes, which I am having right now, I've just reniced all the running processes to +5 but that did not seem to help. Neither setting them to niceness 19.
2. As suggested in one of the answers. I tried changing the scheduler policy to IDLE using `sudo schedtool -D $(pgrep -u myuser progname -d " ")` and with `sudo sh -c 'for pid in $(pgrep -u myuser progname); do chrt -i -p 0 $pid; done;'` *This seems to improve the situation somewhat.*

Comment: How large are the amounts of memory allocated? Are you exceeding your system memory and having to use the swap partition as a result?

Comment: Which kind of computation is that? Can you define limits on how many CPU cores are used? Please be a bit more specific about the workload.

Comment: You can't get more out of the hardware than it has to give. Computers just don't work well at above 85-90% resource utilization. If you have reached that amount on RAM or CPU, the only solution is to upgrade the hardware.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, I was using swap.

Comment: @slhck There are over 10k processes running, each of which should run in a couple of hours.

Comment: @harrymc That's true of course, I would just like the OS to somehow reserve enough of both to keep responsive and usable. Now I basically have to wait a minute to execute any command which makes it difficult to even kill some processes.

Comment: @harrymc Maybe the question could be answered by and explanation why computers don't work well above 90% resource use.

Comment: So don't run over 10k processes in parallel, and schedule them in smaller batches? Hard to give you advice without knowing specifics about the workload you are running. As with any parallel job execution, there is a tradeoff between performance gain by massive paralellization, and parallelization overhead. The sweet spot is somewhere in between serialized runs and massively parallel runs. You have to test that; it depends on the kind of job and its resource usage, as well as the hardware you have available.

Comment: @slhck Right, but these are independent jobs. There is no issue with communication or anything so the usual trade-offs do not apply.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy could you please [edit] your question to give details of what the tasks are doing? With only the broadest possible view we can only give the most generic answers.

Comment: I guess in your specific case, the question still remains: What process is requiring more than 64 GB of RAM, and what could you do to change that (and thus prevent it or other processes from swapping)? This entirely depends on the particular application. We still don't know what that is. A Python data analysis job? A database server? A build job? Same for the 10K jobs. Are they totally heterogenous and beyond your control? Under Linux you could limit those with `ulimit` in the `security.conf` on a per-user level.

Comment: "Niceness" of a process also depends on your operating system scheduler. Some schedulers actively adapt niceness up from the given value if a task does not get enough (or any) CPU time and as a result you overloading the amount of processes is actively working against the OS trying to be fair to waiting tasks.

Comment: @slhck I've updated the question again. The particular nature of the jobs does not matter here because I want my important system processes (however they may be declared) to take precedence over other processes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are saturating your memory and as a result the operating system has to resort to releasing disc caches and swapping programs and their data out to swap.

Swap is a method to keep a system working when physical memory limits are reached. On a lightly loaded system it can mean that the system keeps working and things get paged out when a pinch occurs and then back in when needed with only minor effects.

Most operating systems flush programs and code out to swap on a "least recently used" basis.  It is difficult to make any kind of assumption about "priority" of memory because memory loads change and "priority" is a slippery slope of subjective judgments about what is more important. What is more important for one system is less so for another. Command line programs are just other programs and it is impossible to distinguish them from other programs run by the user.

As you have a heavily loaded system with lots of processes using lots of memory you are hitting a problem with contention. The moment the operating system tries to page something out to disk to free up some memory another process has already requested some other pages that need to be brought back in. Every request to get something back in pushes something else out.

Among 10,000 processes how could any system determine what should take priority over "system" command line program requests which look like any other program request?

The other problem is hard drive seek times. For old style HDDs the time to move the drive head and begin a read or write is of the order of 9.5 milliseconds. With lots of requests happening at once for different areas that seek time can dominate over everything else and reduce actual useful time and bandwidth to surprisingly small figures. An SSD can help, but if you are memory limited then it can only help so much.

Similar bottlenecks can happen all over the system and present different symptoms. The operating system can manage large numbers of simultaneous programs, but it is still "just" a program itself and needs time in amongst everything else. Swap file usage is just one of the most extreme bottlenecks.

Flooding a system in this manner and just expecting it to "deal with it" is not a good idea.

If you are consistently using more memory than you have then the answer is to buy more memory. If you have thousands of processes contending for hard drive time to read or write data then you need to spread the load across more machines or drives.

---

For your other situation, with 10,000 active processes you problem is both one of contention and unrealistic expectations.

One problem is that "niceness" is not necessarily always a lower priority.  It depends on the operating system scheduler and adding more and more processes can actually work against having a fair and useful system as you end up cutting down the amount of time allocated to any given process.

See this question from our Unix sister site [How is nice working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90344/67299) which describes the Completely Fair Scheduler:

> The CFS has a target latency for the scheduling duration. Smaller target latencies yield better interactivity, but as the target latency decreases, the switching overhead increases, thus decreasing the overall throughput.
>
> ...
>
> Now consider two processes, one with a niceness of 0 (the default), the other with a niceness of 5. The proportional difference between the corresponding weights is roughly 1/3, meaning that the higher priority process receives a timeslice of approximately 15 milliseconds while the lower priority process receives a timeslice of 5 milliseconds.

Under this scheduler the niceness means that your 10,000 processes *should* get less time, but due to the sheer number of them you may be hitting the bottom limit of the time slice value for "fair" scheduling and meaning that no one gets a good sized slice of time. You could even be hitting a limit where pulling tasks on or off the CPUs is dominating in time.

This is effectively the same as hard drive contention. You are forcing your system to spend more time swapping between processes than spending any useful time working on any given process.

You can find out more about the scheduler at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Using a more sensible number of processes (100 to 200) results in a reasonable amount of time being split between OS tasks and your processes.

Rather than starting 10,000 tasks at once you should start new ones up as old ones finish.

Comment: Right, so swapping is definitely an issue but does not really answer my questions. I would like to do something like reserve half a GB for the system so it can keep running smoothly. Also, my 10k processes barely consume any memory so that must be a different issue.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy define "system". As I was trying to get across in my answer what you are calling "system" is really just a bunch of "other programs" that have no special privileges and must fight for processor and hard drive time the same as everything else. There might be core parts of the kernel that can be kept in memory, but most things you do to kill processes or list directories are nothing more than *just another program*. There is no mechanism to keep a non-running program in RAM or keep space reserved for it when it may never use it.

Comment: Do your 10k processes consume data from the disk? Are they constantly reading/writing? What do they do? You've not told us anything about them apart from that there are a lot.

Comment: I think this question is too vague to be answerable and should be put on hold until revised. A general answer will not help the OP in their specific case, but we don't know enough about the specific situation in order to provide an adequate solution for the problem either…

Comment: @slhck I had thought with the comments left by OP that they had told us enough, but now it seems otherwise. Some resource is being starved, but we have no idea of what without more specific details.

Comment: @slhck I have updated the question. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it has some good advice even though it does not solve my problem. :)

Comment: @CorporalTouchy I was editing to add some more on CPU contrntion and scheduling.

Comment: The scheduler information is useful. I wish there was a way to tell the scheduler that some processes always should be scheduled and drop the lower limit for the rest.

Comment: It seems that it does, it's not niceness you want but a priority setting in the man page link it mentions being able to set the "scheduling policy" as well as the niceness. SCHED_IDLE seems to be intended for ultra-low priority stuff but it may still be that your large number of processes is still causing contention elsewhere. A much more extreme value of niceness might help you, but it sounds like you are hitting some other limit.

Comment: @Mokubai Do you know of any tools that allow using those syscalls from the command line? Hm...there is a thing called schedtool.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy `chrt -i -p 0 <pid>` [sounds like what you might want to try](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html) or `chrt -i 0 <command>`